# Using Variables in Angular Form Validators

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, forms, validation

I'm trying to use a variable or enum in my form validators for my Angular application. For example instead of

```
TestValue: ['', [Validators.min(0), Validators.max(72)]];
```

having the numbers hardcoded in, I would like to pass in either an enum or a variable in the Validators argument that would have those number values so I can use them across components.

Is this possible?

Comment: yes. That's the reason parameters are accepted.

Comment: how would I add this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kjamp. Yes you can set variables value to validate form. Please have to to the following code:

In Component file:

```
form: FormGroup;
min;
max;
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.min = 0;
    this.max = 72;
    this.createForm(this.min, this.max);
}

createForm(min, max) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
        capacity: ['', [Validators.min(min), Validators.max(max)]],
    });
}

submit() {
    console.log(this.form.value);
    console.log(this.form.controls['capacity'].errors);
}
```

In your your HTML file

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <input type="number" formControlName="capacity" name="capacity" />
    <button>Submit</button>      
</form>
```

I hope this will help you to find your expected solution. Thank you.